# What is the distinction between copying text between a region BEG/END, and copying a region?

Tags: kill-ring

I was trying to add a custom functionality when using `C-u` before the "copying" command or `kill-ring-save`. So I jumped into the source code (pasted below for convenience) to examine what it originally does.

*For brevity I will use the default binding `M-w` instead of `M-x kill-ring-save`.*

It happens that doing `C-u M-w` sets the optional argument REGION to non-nil. From the function docstring, that would not just copy the text between BEG and END but also copy the region.

I did not understand that and so I tried out `C-u M-w`. But I saw no difference between `M-w` and `C-u M-w`.

**Can someone please provide a way in which I can distinguish the behavior between the two?**

---

### Update

On closer inspection, I realized that actually `C-u M-w` and `M-w` will do the exact same thing.. because `(prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)` will return `1` if no prefix arg is used, and will return `4` if `C-u` is used. In either case the REGION variable will be set to `non-nil` and the `region-extract-function` will be used.

So the core question is:

**When does the REGION argument not get set to a non-nil value?** *Wouldn't `prefix-numeric-value` ALWAYS return something non-nil?*

---

### Source code of `kill-ring-save`

```el
(defun kill-ring-save (beg end &optional region)
  "Save the region as if killed, but don't kill it.
In Transient Mark mode, deactivate the mark.
If `interprogram-cut-function' is non-nil, also save the text for a window
system cut and paste.

If you want to append the killed line to the last killed text,
use \\[append-next-kill] before \\[kill-ring-save].

The optional argument REGION if non-nil, indicates that we're not just copying
some text between BEG and END, but we're copying the region.

This command is similar to `copy-region-as-kill', except that it gives
visual feedback indicating the extent of the region being copied."
  ;; Pass mark first, then point, because the order matters when
  ;; calling `kill-append'.
  (interactive (list (mark) (point)
             (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)))
  (copy-region-as-kill beg end region)
  ;; This use of called-interactively-p is correct because the code it
  ;; controls just gives the user visual feedback.
  (if (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
      (indicate-copied-region)))
```

Comment: There's no difference unless you customize `region-extract-function` or `filter-buffer-substring-function`: by default `filter-buffer-substring` will be called in both cases.

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks! Can you please make that an answer. I see that as the `delete` var is set to `'delete` (and not `'delete-only`), `region-extract-function` simply ends up being a wrapper for `filter-buffer-substring`.

Comment: @abo-abo I have updated my question.. I came to a realization that the REGION var would never be able to be `nil`..

Comment: I agree that the doc string is unclear - not helpful in this regard - in fact, **horrible**. It should say what it means by "*we're copying the region*".  There is a precise meaning, and it is not at all conveyed by the existing doc string. I've filed [Emacs bug #21315](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21315) for this.

Comment: Argument `REGION` is never `nil` *interactively*. It can be `nil` from Lisp. Again, the doc string is poor.